# Insert Base64Encoded string returns Incorrect string value (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, base64

I'm trying to insert a Base64Encoded string and sometimes it returns me the MySQL error: `Incorrect string value: '\xFBy\x1Eh\x00...' for column 'Data' at row 1 (error code: 1366, State: HY000)`

The query I run is simple, like:

```
UPDATE Table SET Data='BASE64ENCODED STRING'
```

Important to note however is that the incorrect string value error does not always occur. If I repeat the exact same query again, it accepts the string...?

The `Data-column` is of type `LONGTEXT` and has the `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation.

The `connection` is also using the `utf8mb4` character set with `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation.

What am I doing wrong and how is it possible that when I run the exact same query again, it doesn't throw the error and inserts (updates) the value?

I have already checked the base64 encoded string, which does not contain a string like: `\xFBy\x1Eh\x00`

*I use prepared statements in order to execute the update*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to add the N prefix in front of the string to be inserted. For example, the following query:

```
UPDATE Table SET Data='BASE64ENCODED STRING'
```

had to be changed to:

```
UPDATE Table SET Data=N'BASE64ENCODED STRING'
```